# River crossing with boat

Tags: combinatorics

Alan, Bill, Charly, Dean and Edgar are going to cross a river to reach the opposite river bank by using a small boat. The rules are very strict because the river is deep and dangerous:
For the boat not to sink, the 5 friends must be seated one behind the other, starting from the lightest, in order of weight. All friends are of different weight!
All they have with them is a balance scale. Given that their time is limited, they must determine the order by the least number of weightings. Can you help them?

Starting with A+B we determine AB. 
Say we have $A>B$. Then we add C and weight it against, say, the lightest. $B+C$. If we have $C<B$ then $C<B<A$. But we can't go on with such a simplistic approach. There must be something clever which I am missing.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Donald Knuth, "The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 3, Sorting and Searching", section 5.3.1, shows that the minimum number of comparisons is 7.  He attributes the method to H. B. Demuth, Ph.D. thesis, Stanford University, Oct. 1956.

Comment: Since we often have real river crossing problems here I suggest a different title.

Comment: @awkward: I am a bit confused. The document you suggest ("The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 3, Sorting and Searching"), gives a solution in 7 weighings, whereas TonyK solution needs 9. Which one is correct?

Comment: @PreechapakTekasuk If Knuth says he can do it in 7 comparisons, I am inclined to believe him.  $7 < 9$.

Comment: @awkward: Thank you for that correction. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to add:**
The algorithm presented in this answer is not optimal, as @awkward points out in a comment to the OP. There is [a faster method, due to H. B. DeMuth](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cYULBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA184&ots=KKyyMgOq5I&dq=H.%20B.%20Demuth%2C%20Ph.D.%20thesis&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q=H.%20B.%20Demuth,%20Ph.D.%20thesis&f=false), that requires only seven comparisons.

The algorithm given below is the best you can do if your sequence of comparisons has to be specified in advance.

---

John M. Gamble's [Sorting Networks](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html) is the place to go when you want to sort a small list with the fewest comparisons. Selecting N=5 gives you [this list of nine weighings to perform](http://jgamble.ripco.net/cgi-bin/nw.cgi?inputs=5&algorithm=best&output=macro):

> SWAP(0, 1);
>   SWAP(3, 4);
>   SWAP(2, 4);
>   SWAP(2, 3);
>   SWAP(0, 3);
>   SWAP(0, 2);
>   SWAP(1, 4);
>   SWAP(1, 3);
>   SWAP(1, 2);

Here, SWAP(x,y) means "Swap x and y if x weighs more than y."

Note that you can't just replace $0$ with $A$, $1$ with $B$ etc, because the numbers refer to positions in the list, not to people. So what you do is this:
Make five flash cards, with the numbers $0,1,2,3,4$ written on them. Give everybody a card. Then SWAP(x,y) means:

> Put the holders of flash cards x and y on the balance scale. If the holder of flash card x weighs more than the holder of flash card y, have them swap cards.

After the nine weighings in the list, have them line up in the order of the cards that they hold.

Comment: TonyK thank you for your reply. Can you possibly explain in a simpler way? I didn't quite understand your method and, most importantly, why this gives the minimum number of weighings.

Comment: @ChenAavaz: I suggest you google Bose-Nelson for more information.

Comment: @TonyK I don't think this is the proper way to reply! I don't understand either - maybe a couple of hints would be more useful than asking us to do a research on google. Btw I did already and didn't find any clear reference, so that someone can understand! Thanking you in advance.

Comment: @TonyK: So in practical terms, who do we weight against whom, and how do we proceed basis each result?

Comment: @CretonLaplace:  the answer gives that.  You could think of them all being in line and the first step is to weigh the first two and put them back with the lighter first.  Then you weigh the fourth and fifth people and put them back in order.  In the third step you weigh the middle person against the one who is now last and so on.

Comment: @RossMillikan: In fairness to Creton, I edited my answer in response to his comment.